# How to get a reference to the current window?

Tags: iphone

Need a ref to the window in which a view is inside (no matter how deep inside). Usually there is only one window in an iPhone app. How would I access that the most easy way? Is there something cooler than getting the app delegate to access the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, UIView has the [`window` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW55)...

Comment: What if you're not in a class that has any UIView objects

Answer (score 8):

To get a currently used window by your application use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
```

Comment: I need to add a view on top of the current view (like an alert message) from the App Delegate, whenever I receive push notification. The rootViewController may or may not be presenting a view controller. How do I do this?